# Proper Holomorphic Mappings

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $A,B$ denote domains in $\mathbb{C}$, and $f:A\rightarrow B$
is a holomorphic mapping. Suppose that $f$ is proper ($f^{-1}$ takes
compact sets to compact sets). Prove that $f(A)=B.$

Comment: $f$ must be non-constant...

Answer (score 10):

A proper map is easily seen to be a closed map. Moreover, a non-constant holomorphic map on a domain in $\mathbb C$ is always an open map (see [Wikipedia, Open Mapping Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29/) for example).

Therefore, $f(A)$ is both open and closed (and non-empty of course), so by connectedness of $B$, $f(A)=B$.

*Edit: Closedness of $f$*.  If $f(x_n)\to y$, then $\{f(x_n), n \in \mathbb N\}\cup \{y\}$ is compact thus $\{x_n, n \in \mathbb N\}\subset f^{-1}(\{f(x_n), n \in \mathbb N\}\cup \{y\})$ lives in a compact set, therefore a subsequence of $(x_n)$ is convergent to some $x\in A$, satisfying of course $f(x)=y$, so $f$ is closed.